# PHP database connection code no longer working on host site

Tags: php

I have a PHP site with a mySQL database that I'm working on. I'm running Apache, PHP, and mySQL on my development machine, and my code all works just fine. A week ago, I uploaded my code and database to my organization's web host (it's a non-profit group, so the host is not a dedicated in-house server, but rented space.) At that point, the code worked perfectly on the host site.

I added a few new pages this past week, so uploaded them today and went to test. And lo and behold, my code (existing code, not the new stuff) returns a database connection error.

The host company insists that the issue is on my end. How is that possible, if the code was working perfectly just last week and no changes have been made to the existing code? It seems to me the only possible explanation is that there was a change in the host's environment.

I'm pretty new to PHP, so I'm hoping someone can help me out here and explain whether it is possible or whether the host company's tech support is clueless.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: The error message will almost certainly be `Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`. Does the same code work on your local or test box?

Comment: @Samir - no, the error is my own die message in my code: $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ( "Can't connect to the MySQL Server/Database" );

The connect variables have not changed since I successfully tested it on the host site.

Comment: @EmmyS There are a few things that would cause this. You need to determine which one it is (authentication, hostname, connectivity, etc). Your php log should contain the php error that will help you determine this.

Comment: check if you are missing a connect to db call ,or overwrited stuff by accident :)

Comment: Have you tried returning `mysqli_connect_error()` to see what the MySQL client library thinks the error is?

Comment: More specifically: `$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME) or die ( "Can't connect to the MySQL Server/Database: " . mysqli_connect_error() );`  Chances are it will be the error Samir mentioned above, but at least that'll be a starting location...

Comment: @R.Bemrose - I just copied your line into my code, uploaded to the host, and retried. Here's the result: "Can't connect to the MySQL Server/Database: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)". Same as the error I posted in my comment to arnorhs's answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your php error_log file. The database error will probably be listed there.

Comment: error_log shows the following error: "PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect() [<a href='function.mysqli-connect'>function.mysqli-connect</a>]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) in /hermes/web06/b2247/pow.pcbadmin/htdocs/webTests/loginForm.php on line 9 " where line 9 is the line quoted in my comment to Samir above.

Comment: @EmmyS This sounds like the mysql server is not running. Check that your DB_HOST constant is set correctly. If you have shell access, check that you can connect to the db using CLI.

Comment: Either mysql is not running or you have the wrong host name. @Rob is right, try echoing out the contents of the DB_HOST constant...

Comment: The DB_HOST is set by me in an include file. How will echoing the content help? The issue is whether the constant that I'm using matches what the hostname actually is, and as of a week ago it did.

Comment: As for the mySQL server not running: my access to the server is limited to a web interface called mySQLAdmin. But I am able to get at the database via that interface, so I'm assuming the server must be running.

Comment: yes, well, mysql might not be running on that particular host. Maybe the phpmyadmin interface is set up to connect to a remote mysql host. Echoing the DB_HOST where you're connecting will clearly print out which host you are connecting to. Sometimes it's a good way to realize some obvious mistake that you make - at least I make obvious mistakes all the time, and I consider myself pretty seasoned, so why shouldn't everybody else?

Comment: Thank you, @arnorhs. That was indeed the issue. The mySQLAdmin interface apparently does connect to a different host than the hosting company told me to use for actual connections. The host I was supposed to use was down. Kind of ticks me off that they insisted the issue was on my end, when it was their server that was down.

Comment: Yes, that's a hosting company for you :-) For some reason, the most obvious problems are always the hardest ones to solve...

Comment: Voting for this answer, even though the actual answer came in one of the comments further down (by same poster.)